# TwebBrowser Zoom/Gesture is not working for firemonkey/iOs in XE4 when open a pdf file

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, twebbrowser, delphi-xe4

I want to display PDF within iOS application, so far the only way I find is open it in TwebBrowser.

A.It is displaying in "fit to page width" zoom as default

B.There is no "zoom" function

WebBrowser1.Navigate(file://mypdf.pdf')

How to

1. I want to change the zoom after open the file (My solution encounter q#2)
2. Make the zoom work (My solution encounter q#3)
3. Make the gesture as work just like web page

For #1:

I chagne WebBrowser1.height/width in run-time, it will auto scale(zoom?) as "Fit to width".

Yes it works, and vertical scroll bar works with a flaw - it will not bounce back on edge -> you can scroll all the way down..

Neither the horizontal scroll, not reacting at all....

*This is because the pdf is A4, not sure what will happen for a landscape style

For #2:

Beside using button clicks to zoom, I add a gestureManager.

Then add Form1.ongesture just like the "iOS Interactive Gestures - Image Zoom" example.

Yes it works, but same thing - no vertical bounce, no horizontal scroll.

*ScrollBox does not work, it will not work with any thing has a build-in vert/hori scroll bars

For #3
:
I go even further, write control for up/down/left/right

Change WebBrowser1.Position.X/Y and WebBrowser1.height/width to make it looks like "scrolling"

Yes it works... but two custom gesture controls are making it really hard to control

(EventInfo.Distance and EventInfo.X/Y, those 2 controls are kinda overlaping to eachother if you run in iPhone)

The wosrt part is, the WebBrowser1 will be on top of ANY compenment, regardless parent/child structure .
The second worst part is the limitation of margin is hard to code, somehow it can always scroll over the limit.....

I "feel" if changing the zoom on/after open, and make it open with both vert/hori scrool bars visible.
Then the horizontal bar should work -> i only need to deal with zoom -> pretty close to prefect.

Of course the best way is to make it work like a web page, like 
WebBrowser1.Navigate('http://www.embarcadero.com/') -> both scrollbars works, zoom work.
but...maybe need service pack N for this?

I appreciate for any ideas or code answers.

This damned monkey is on fire and its always hard to find an answer from it.

Answer (score 0):

An article was posted today on [The Hacker's Corner](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/ao/) called [Getting TWebBrowser on iOS to zoom](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/ao/2013/05/15/39460). It suggests a one-line fix to the FMX.WebBrowser.iOS.pas unit. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug, and fixed in the XE4 update.