# How do you get TWebBrowser components to respond to gestures?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'd like to be able to use gestures with the TWebBrowser component. If I do this:

1. Create a blank FireMonkey application.
2. Drop a TabControl on the form, add two TabItems, align the TabControl to client.
3. Drop a WebBrowser on one of the tabs.
4. Add a GestureManager to the form, assign it to the WebBrowser, activate the left and right standard gestures, code a simple ShowMessage in the OnGesture event.

When I then run the application gestures over the web browser don't do anything. OTOH, if I attach the GestureManager to a TabControl then it does generate the event--as long as I'm not gesturing over the web browser.

So, how does on get a TWebBrowser component to respond to gestures?

UPDATE:
As per Ken's suggestion, I tried dropping a TWebBrowser on a plain form. Same results ... WebBrowser does not respond to gestures, and reassigning GestureManager to the form results in the form responding to gestures.

Comment: What Delphi version? FireMonkey (FMX) changes rapidly, so the version is relevant, and you should add a tag for that specific version as well as the generic Delphi tag. Have you searched for other gesture-related posts here for FMX's TWebBrowser here, like [Twebbrowser Zoom/Gesture is not working for firemonkey/iOS in XE4 when open a pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16371768/62576)?

Comment: Hi Ken ... It's 10.1 Berlin and, yes, I did search for other posts and saw the one you mentioned. Thanks for responding.

Comment: As I mentioned, you should add the tag for the specific version when asking questions related to FMX. I've done so for you here. If you've looked at other posts, you should say so in your post so people don't waste time pointing them out. :-) What happens when you skip step 2 and drop the TWebBrowser directly on the form instead, without the tab control? When trying to solve a problem, the first step is to remove possible contributors (like other controls/components) to minimize the issue.